# row.getValue() doesn't work but row[1] does

Tags: arcpy, cursor

for some reason I can't get row.getValue to work properly... my script will only work if I use row[0] and get the value manually but I am sure the location/order of my fields will change from dataset to dataset.
This works:

```
    mylist = []
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, "*") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[12] == value:
                mylist.append(row[2])
```

However this does not...

```
    fieldname = "Coolfield"
    mylist = []
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, "*") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row.getValue(fieldname) == value:
                mylist.append(row[2])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 16):

You are observing a difference between what arcpy and arcpy.da cursors return:

- [arcpy cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Row/018z0000008r000000/):

> The Row object represents the row of a table. The Row object is
>   returned from InsertCursor, SearchCursor, and UpdateCursor.

and a Row object has a getValue method.

- [arcpy.da cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/):

> Returns an iterator of lists. The order of values in the list matches
>   the order of fields specified by the `field_names` argument.

and an iterator of lists does not have a getValue method.

I don't think it is a concern that the location/order of your fields varies because you specify their order using the `field_names` argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do something like `getValue()` with `arcpy.da` cursors, you can do something like this:

```
mylist = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(FC, '*') as rows:
    idx = rows.fields.index("Coolfield")
    for row in rows:
        mylist.append(row[idx)])
```

Answer (score 1):

To save yourself some work trying to make arcpy.da cursors (search, update, and insert) easier to work with, I've made a [cursor helper](https://gist.github.com/BrianBunker/4a5f80ebce42082dce65) that allows bracket and dot notation with column names. So,

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ('MyValue', 'SHAPE@')) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        my_value = row[0]
        shape = print(row[1]
```

Becomes:

```
arcpy_cursor_utility as acu

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ('MyValue', 'SHAPE@')) as rows:
    for row in acu.search_cursor(rows):
        my_value = row.MyValue or row['MyValue']
        shape = row['SHAPE@']  # But not row.SHAPE@ because of the @ token
```

Note that this alteration to the out-of-the-box cursors has a performance hit, so if performance is critical, please evaluate critically.

Hope you find this useful. https://gist.github.com/BrianBunker/4a5f80ebce42082dce65